# Fiducials on PCBs

Tags: pcb

Is it alright for me to place fiducials on the top layer right above the bottom layer PCB traces like this?

Running DRC on KiCAD does not pose any potential issues, but would just like to confirm this.

[image]

Comment: If the fiducial's purpose is aligning the PCB for assembly purposes ... fine. If it's for aligning different PCB layers during etching/stacking, no. But to be certain, ask your PCB fab and assembly houses.

Comment: Is this 2 layers or multi?

Answer (score 2):

Fiducials are an aid to align the pick & place machine coordinates to the physical PCB (x-y & angular offsets, and scaling). The fiducial location is located by optical means. That means the fiducial needs to have an area clear of features about the fiducial on the same layer.

In your case, having features on a layer different from the fiducial, there is no problem since the PCB material is opaque, i.e., the features on the bottom of the board can't be seen by device used to locate the fiducials on the top of the board.